# Configure Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I tried to configure Spring Boot with Hibernate:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;

import org.datalis.plugin.database.dao.TerminalsService;
import org.datalis.plugin.database.models.TerminalsModel;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Qualifier("terminalsService")
public class TerminalsDaoHibernate implements TerminalsService {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public TerminalsModel getTerminalToken(String terminalToken) throws Exception {
        TerminalsModel terminal = null;
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        try {

            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            terminal = (TerminalsModel) session.get(TerminalsModel.class, terminalToken);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw new Exception("Error");
        }
        return terminal;
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
14:47:34,323 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead
14:47:34,323 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:255)
```

What is the proper way to configure @Transactional properly?
Do I need to use Transaction is a different way?

Comment: You are trying to start another transaction. Don't do `entityManager.getTransaction().begin();` etc. That is what `@Transactional` is already doing for you.

Comment: Can you show me how I can use EntityManager with Hibernate?

Comment: You are already doing it, the problem is you are trying to start another transaction. You are fighting with `@Transactional` (which as the name implies handles your transaction). You only need 2 lines of code in your method 1, get the `Session` from the `EntityManager`, 2. return and get the value from the `Session`. (Although I don't see why would need a `Session` for that at all).

Comment: Can you paste here please official answer with sample code so I can up vote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `@Transactional` and still are trying to manually start a transaction. Either do manual transaction management (i.e remove the `@Transactional`) or embrace `@Transactional` by removing the manual transaction management code.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public TerminalsModel getTerminalToken(String terminalToken) throws Exception {
    TerminalsModel terminal = null;
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    return (TerminalsModel) session.get(TerminalsModel.class, terminalToken);
}
```

However I don't see why you would want to use plain Hibernate over JPA here. The same result can be achieved by using JPA.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public TerminalsModel getTerminalToken(String terminalToken) throws Exception {
    return entityManager.find(TerminalsModel.class, terminalToken);
}
```

Generally there is no need to use the plain Hibernate API over JPA with the current state of the JPA API.

Comment: Can I ask in order to select table row by username and password how I have to update the code? (two WHERE arguments)

Comment: No as that is a different question (your question here was about transactions).